# VB.Net - Delete First Row Data in DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, ado.net

Good day.
I am a newbie in VB.net and SQL.
Now I am working with datagridview in vb.net and I encountering an error when I try to delete a data at first row in a table.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Sales_CustomerList". The conflict occurred in database "BestSmileShop", table "dbo.Sales", column 'custID'.

Here's my code:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim dr As DataRow
cid = txtCid.Text
dt = DsCust1.Tables("CustomerList")
dr = dt.Rows.Find(cid)
dr.Delete()
```

Do anyone have idea? Can explain the problem to me? Thank you:)
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show us your database schema.
The error occurs because your Database has a Table called "Sales" which references the Table "CustomerList". There something was sold (I am guessing this from the name) to a Customer on the CustomerList. This is done through the column Sales.custID, which is called a foreign key (FK). When you try to delete the Customer, this is not possible because the FK tells SQL that the Customer should not be deleted, unless there are no sales referencing him /her. 
If you think about it, this is logical - if you delete the customer, you would never know to whom something was sold, essentially creating a black hole in the data.

Things you should google:

- Foreign Key
- Database design
- Entity Framework - this is more modern than working with databases directly and has the advantage that you can easily map your objects to database data.

Comment: Thanks for willing to help me:)
After I delete all reference from `CustomerList` table to `Sales` table, the `delete` function runs well again.
I will go through the things you recommended me to research.

Comment: @VillagerA If you can open the database in Visual Studio Server Explorer try to look at the definition of Sales. There should be a List of all Foreign Keys on the left side

Comment: Preventing deleting is part of what Foreign Keys are for.  Are you sure removing this reference is something you want to do?  Instead consider using some sort of object structure, like CSLA.NET, which implements a transaction boundary.  Then you can delete those rows that can be deleted, and leave those which cannot.  Otherwise you're going to end up with orphaned records.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom You are right. I am just want to clear all data in database for doing testing on my application but the system doesn't allow me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The record you are trying to delete is being referenced in the "Sales" table (by foreign key).

In order to delete from the CustomerList table, you'll also need to delete all references to this customer in the Sales table.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had just delete them and the `delete` function runs well.
Thank you for willing to help :)

Comment: I don't think this is fixing the problem, but rather merely side-stepping it.  The problem here is quite simply that you're trying to delete something that you probably shouldn't be deleting.  That foreign key was implemented for a reason.

Comment: My suggestion would be to do your testing on a clean, data-free database.  SQL Server can produce a script that essentially copies a database's schema without copying its data and that can be used to create a fresh copy.